# CSS Z-Index menu dropdown bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I've been trying to fix this for 2 days now with no success and it's driving me insane.

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrdlu.png)

Basically, when I click the input and the menu drops down it overlaps with the dropdown menu that's below it. I'm using the Wordpress ClickBoutique theme.

Link: [click here](http://urbanapparel.ro/shop/femei/tricou-clasic-ua-ga32/)

I've tried giving them different z-index values, even overwriting the inline rules with !important but it doesn't seem to work. It appears that a js (maybe jQuery) function changes those z-index values based on which dropdown menu the user clicks.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You have conflicting z-index declarations, you need to remove the below where commented (lines 236 and 243 in styles.css)

```
.site-content .jq-selectbox,
.widget .jq-selectbox {
    font: 16px 'Roboto Condensed';
    min-width: 180px;
    width: 100%;
    /* z-index: 98 !important; REMOVE */
}
.site-content .jq-selectbox,
.widget .jq-selectbox:first-child {
    font: 16px 'Roboto Condensed';
    min-width: 180px;
    width: 100%;
    /* z-index: 99 !important; REMOVE  */
}
```

The add the below so the 'top' dropdown overlaps the 'bottom' one.

```
#pa_color-styler{
   z-index:9999;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) Yes but then when I hover the Cart button it overlapps with that.. like this: http://i.imgur.com/e9TCxTD.png :( this theme is so badly coded

Comment: @csergiu_ro - its fairly time consuming and tricky inline debugging a live site with a lot of extraneous code - could you post a self contained example in your question (and maybe a jsfiddle)?

Answer (score 0):

remove the z-index:98 of these to classes in your style.css line 243 :

.site-content .jq-selectbox, .widget .jq-selectbox:first-child
.site-content .jq-selectbox, .widget .jq-selectbox

Answer (score 0):

1) `.site-content .jq-selectbox, .widget .jq-selectbox:first-child`

2) `.site-content .jq-selectbox, .widget .jq-selectbox`

You just need to remove the z-index property from the above classes.
It's conflicting with the z-index properties in another classes of yours.